# File not found exception (java.io.FileNotFoundException) while uploading files to jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I've written a small code in my project where a jsp page takes few parameters like name, cost  and image file as parameters as input and stores in the Mysql database.When i'm uploading the file and clicking submit, i get file not found exception.

java.io.FileNotFoundException : 0.jpg (No such file or directory)

[After hitting submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkTk5.png)

I've tried uploading from multiple locations. It didn't change. I have a query:.Why is the images absolute path not being displayed in exception. Is the issue related to this?

This is the piece of code that takes the input.

```
<form name="f" action="re_pro_insert.jsp" method="post" onsubmit="return valid()">
.
.
.

    <tr>
      <td align="center"><font color="#333366" size="+1" face="Georgia, Times New Roman, Times, serif"><strong>Product 
                          Image:</strong></font>
      </td>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="file" name="proimage" size="8" id="b" vlaue="jj">
      </td>
    </tr>
```

This is the part where the file is read to be stored. this is throwing the exception

```
FileInputStream fis=null;

String a = request.getParameter("comname");

String b = request.getParameter("proname");
String c = request.getParameter("wardate");
String d = request.getParameter("proimage");
String e = request.getParameter("prorate");
String f="";
String g=f+d;

File image=new File(g);

fis=new FileInputStream(image);
```

Any idea?

I'm running this on Apache Tomcat 7 through eclipse.

Thank you.

Comment: @Jens: Nope. That ain't gonna work when the webserver runs at a physically different machine than the webbrowser. You just need to make sure that the webbrowser sends the file **contents** not the file path. Then, in the webserver just read the file contents. A decent webbrowser doesn't send the full file path along in the metadata. Only a bad webbrowser (e.g. IE) does, but this should be corrected in the webserver's code. See also the duplicate for an elaborate instruction on how to upload files using JSP/Servlet.

Comment: @BalusC: Thanks for the info. I didn't knew what to search for. Got my problem solved after referring to that page and a few google searches.